# PHP Dependency Injection issue

Tags: php

Ey guys, I am trying to learn Dependency Injection and I wrote this code:

```
class User {
    public $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'Alex';
    }
}

class Article {
    public $author;

    public function __construct(User $author) {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

    public function getAuthorName() {
        return $this->author->getName();
    }
}

$news = new Article(10);
echo $news->getAuthorName();
```

However, I am getting WSOD. What had I done wrong in it ?

Comment: In constructor you inject `10` instead of `User` object.

Comment: The constructor of `Article` requires a user, not an integer; instead, you should do this: `$news = new Article(new User(10));
echo $news->getAuthorName();`

Comment: What means: `WSOD` ? Also `$news = new Article(10);` -> `$news = new Article(new User(10));`

Comment: @Rizier123 WSOD stands for White Screen Of Death

Comment: WSOD means White Screen of Death

Comment: @Rizier123 White Screen Of Death :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified wrong instance.Use the code below

```
<?php
class User {
    public $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'Alex';
    }
}

class Article {
    public $author;

    public function __construct(User $author) {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

    public function getAuthorName() {
        return $this->author->getName();
    }
}

$news = new Article(new  User(10));
echo $news->getAuthorName(); //Outputs Alex
```

Hope this helps you